# MVC HTML putting automatic break

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

```
<h2>Order</h2>
<h1> @Html.ActionLink("Create Order", "CreateOrder", "Home")</h1>
```

I have the above code in the cshtml in the View of MVC however the result is like

Order

Create Order

How do i get it to look like:

Order Create Order

Comment: Then pass "CreateOrder" instead of "Create Order" as first parameter of Html.ActionLink method.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my question

Comment: As the question was updated my answer is to read about `html inline and block elements`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple css stuff. If you want to display it like that, you have to set for instance

```
h1, h2 { display: inline; }
```

in your stylesheet. It has nothing to do with MVC nor with ASP.NET.

Comment: I added '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
h2 { display: inline; }
--->
</STYLE>'
however it's still the same

Comment: @YagneshCangi, I'm afraid H1 has to be inline as well.